# How to use testing with EntityFramework and Moq or Castle whereas Nuget EF packages does not have InternalsVisibleTo?

Tags: c#, .net, moq, internalsvisibleto

For my own projects i need to expose EF functionality with overriding some internal classes. It is a way to create Proxy classes with Emit or Moq or Castle and works with them, but it works only with EF compiled from GitHub sources. This sources have InternalsVisibleTo attribute for DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 assemblies and Emit/Moq/Castle works fine.
But when i try to use EF nuget package, i see that this version does not have InternalsVisibleTo attributes (only one).
[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to test specifically? In general you shouldn't need to override EF functionality, but rather just mock out your EF models using 'virtual' properties.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Im trying to create my map some additional C# methods to EF (for example, Convert.ToInt32 -> "cast(XX to int)". I dont see any real reasons for why EF team does not implement this in their code and it is very nessesary for my projects. It is real to create additional CallTranslators. but only with InternalsVisibleTo.